# How to find time period over which usage was minimum over a day through database

Tags: python, database, algorithm, database-design

I'm working on a project where I monitor pressure inside a pipe once every 5 seconds in a day and store it over memory in MCU or on the cloud (this still has to be decided.) After 24 Hours I need to calculate the minimum usage over a time period from that data. So I would like if people can suggest me if there is any smart algorithm that I can read and apply it. I have low knowledge of databases so I will appreciate your views.
We are going to use python and I am going to code on the raspberry pi.

PS: I am noob in database algorithm so please keep that in mind.

Comment: In future, we might have to analyze data of the month and find the minimum usage on certain days throughout the month.
Because usage will change based on its weekend or weekdays.
Probably for that, we may do analysis overcloud since its a heavy task for an MCU (raspberry pi).
Looking for algorithm suggestion that I can read and implement.

Comment: Since this question is not about a specific piece of code with which you are struggling, I would suggest https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JacobIRR my question regarding which algorithm will be the fastest to calculate m, I am not looking for code but the idea how to do it, code part I can do it myself if I understand the algorithm

Comment: @PrashantGupta, provided your pipeline user population size is not too high, python should be able to handle it with ease. However, this forum is unlikely to help you if you do not put down some code, say what it is supposed to do, and what difficulties you are having with it. Alternatively, you could give more details on what the algorithm is supposed to do, making it more interesting. As your question stands, finding a minimum value every 24 hours in python is a two or three liner - perhaps not enough to keep the mind alive.

Comment: @Dlamini So my project is going to monitor the water usage in a household. This sensor will keep monitoring the pressure and temperature value every 5 sec and push it to the cloud. Also, it will store a certain number of reading locally(TBD how many to store locally). From the locally stored data, it will try to find the time period throughout the day when water is least used. based on the analyzed data it will perform some calibration when water is least used.

Comment: @Dlamini contd:
So in order to choose when to calibrate the sensor we need to find the time period when water is least used say like 3 am no one going to use so calibrate during that period. Right now I am in the design phase so I thought someone points me in the right direction which algorithm can be used. I am looking for more theoretical answer rather than a code because if understand the algorithm I can code it.

Comment: My current thoughts on this is :

Comment: My current thoughts on this is
Since we recording reading every 5sec, so in 1 min I have 12 reading. I will analyze and store this as one reading to an array of size 60 if the water was used then I push 1 to an array if not I push 0. By doing that in the end I will have an array which will tell me over an hour we used water or not. by using that I can poll when water usage is least.
Let me know if this approach is good

Comment: @PrashantGupta might work but sounds a little complicated. Have a look at the flowchart I am posting as an answer. You can modify it or question further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a process flow which should give you the minimum use period and also give you a data record.

[image]